# Admob plugin dosen't work with Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, admob, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, banner-ads

I hope you can help me with this problem. I have tried EVERYTHING the last 5 days, but I fail every time.
I have buildt a simple app using HTML5, CSS and little bit of Javascript.The app works fine.Than I want a simple banner ad that shows at the bottom of the app.I just can't get it to work. Sometimes a black box shows up at the bottom, that's all, but not ad. I'm not very good with Javascript so the problem is maby with the code, but I've copied most of it from plugin exemple.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-admob

I'm using:
- Phonegap 6.1.2 (Build Service)
- admob-phonegap plugin`(<plugin name="phonegap-admob" spec="4.2.1" />)`
- Other plugins that work fine.

What I need:
- Only a small banner ad at the bottom of the page.

Platform:
- Only Andriod

In my config.xml I have this line:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-admob" spec="4.2.1" />
```

In my index.html inside the `<script></script>` tags, I have this code:

```
<script>
var isAppForeground = true;

    function initAds() {
      if (admob) {
        var adPublisherIds = {
          android : {
            banner : "ca-app-pub-1467389904102750/404191XXXX",
          }
        };

        var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

        admob.setOptions({
          publisherId:      admobid.banner,
          interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,

        });

        registerAdEvents();

      } else {
        alert('AdMobAds plugin not ready');
      }
    }

    function onAdLoaded(e) {
      if (isAppForeground) {
        if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
          console.log("An interstitial has been loaded and autoshown. If you want to load the interstitial first and show it later, set 'autoShowInterstitial: false' in admob.setOptions() and call 'admob.showInterstitialAd();' here");
        } else if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE_BANNER) {
          console.log("New banner received");
        }
      }
    }

    function onPause() {
      if (isAppForeground) {
        admob.destroyBannerView();
        isAppForeground = false;
      }
    }

    function onResume() {
      if (!isAppForeground) {
        setTimeout(admob.createBannerView, 1);
        setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
        isAppForeground = true;
      }
    }

    // optional, in case respond to events
    function registerAdEvents() {
      document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
      document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdFailedToLoad, function (e) {});
      document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, function (e) {});
      document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, function (e) {});
      document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLeftApplication, function (e) {});

      document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
      document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
      document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
      initAds();

      // display a banner at startup
      admob.createBannerView();

    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 </script>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Allright, the whole code was correct. The problem was just that I didn't link to Cordova in the Script tag. I read it somewhere that you didn't need it and Phonegap / Cordova would include it automatically. It was all that was needed. Do you want Admob to be displayed (and probably many other plugins), please include

```
<script type = "text / javascript" src = "cordova.js"> </script>.
```